# Will using a display impact performance?

Tags: ubuntu, performance, display

This might be a strange question. I have a very lightweight Ubuntu Server 14.04 box running underneath my TV, and I want to connect my TV to it to monitor some things.

However, since it is a very lightweight server, I cannot have anything impacting it's performance.

So my question is, will using my TV as a monitor for the server impact the server's performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just hooking up a viewing device like a monitor/TV to a display port on your server won't affect performance. Technically the OS is already prepared to send a display signal and waiting for you to hook up a display to receive. The action of sending the signal would not even register as intensive on any machine made since 1980 (just some humor).

If you have to install special drivers, software, etc. to get the display out, it could possibly effect performance. The biggest thing not to do is install a GUI or anything else eating up cycles - like specialized TV-out software for instance.